# In search of a more efficient solution converting Wide data to long data

Tags: r

I want to convert the data from wide to long.I have solved the problem with the reshape package but then I manually had to define which column belonged the "gather columns", if there are hundreds of columns (which is the case in my data) that would be time consuming and a high risk of writing errors.
Does anyone know how to make a more efficient function to reach to this result?

```
id <- 1001:1003
qA2 <- c(10,5,1)
qB2 <- c(11,6,3)
qC2 <- c(10,7,5)
qA3 <- c(15,12,8)
qB3 <- c(18,15,7)
qC3 <- c(19,11,10)

df <- data.frame(id,qA2,qB2,qC2, qA3, qB3, qC3)
df



 id qA2 qB2 qC2 qA3 qB3 qC3
1 1001  10  11  10  15  18  19
2 1002   5   6   7  12  15  11
3 1003   1   3   5   8   7  10
```

Solution with the reshape package:

```
library(reshape2)
df_test <- reshape(df, idvar="id", direction="long", varying=list(c(2,5), c(3,6), c(4,7)),v.names=c("qA", "qB", "qC"),times=2:3) 
df_test
df_test <- df_test[order(df_test$id, df_test$time),]



         id time qA qB qC
1001.2 1001    2 10 11 10
1001.3 1001    3 15 18 19
1002.2 1002    2  5  6  7
1002.3 1002    3 12 15 11
1003.2 1003    2  1  3  5
1003.3 1003    3  8  7 10
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `dplyr` and `tidyr`, here is one way not sure about the efficiency though

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  gather(key, value, -id) %>%
  mutate(key = sub("\\d+", "", key)) %>%
  group_by(key) %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  spread(key, value) %>%
  select(-row)

# A tibble: 6 x 4
#     id    qA    qB    qC
#  <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1  1001    10    11    10
#2  1001    15    18    19
#3  1002     5     6     7
#4  1002    12    15    11
#5  1003     1     3     5
#6  1003     8     7    10
```

Answer (score 2):

With the new version of `tidyr` (`1.0.0`) (already on CRAN, just update it):

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("q"), 
               names_to = "time", 
               names_prefix = "q[A-Z]", 
               values_to = c("qA","qB","qC"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R one liner,

```
df1 <- cbind(id = df$id, (do.call(cbind, lapply(split.default(df[-1], 
                                gsub('\\d+', '', names(df)[-1])), stack))[c(TRUE, FALSE)]))
df1[with(df1, order(id)),]

#    id qA.values qB.values qC.values
#1 1001        10        11        10
#4 1001        15        18        19
#2 1002         5         6         7
#5 1002        12        15        11
#3 1003         1         3         5
#6 1003         8         7        10
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `names_pattern` with `pivot_longer`

```
library(tidyr)
pivot_longer(df, -id, names_to = c(".value", "time"), names_pattern= "(\\D+)(\\d+)")
# A tibble: 6 x 5
#     id time     qA    qB    qC
#  <int> <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1  1001 2        10    11    10
#2  1001 3        15    18    19
#3  1002 2         5     6     7
#4  1002 3        12    15    11
#5  1003 2         1     3     5
#6  1003 3         8     7    10
```